# VS 2019 No Reference Properties available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to set the copy local of the references to false.
But there are no properties [(*refer image)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ArS.png) available for any of the references
I repaired Visual Studio and even reinstalled it but no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: That behavior can be by design for certain project types (but you didn't show us what type of project it is). You might open the project file in an editor to manually change what you want.

Comment: @LexLi It's a .NET Framework Project. Is that what you wanted to know. Pardon me if I didn't get you since I'm new to programming!

Comment: Is there the properties list for System.dll in the reference?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT There is no properties list for System.dll as well.

Comment: @AmolShah Did you install the Universal Windows Platform development for your Visual Studio? If you didn't, could you try to install it to check if the properties page work.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT I didn't install that, I'll give it a try and update you.